# i created two functions, both are working but when i when i put them together they are not

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

> the below function checks if a number is odd or not and logs them

```
function OddNumFinder(x) {
    if (x%2==1) {
    y = console.log(x+' is a odd number');
    x = x%2
    return console.log(x);
    }
}
im_num = []
```

> this function create an array of random number

```
function collConjecture(x) {
    while (x !== 1) {
        if (x%2 == 1) {
            x = (x*3)+1
        } else {
            x = x/2
        }
        im_num.push(x)
    }
}
```

> this works

```
collConjecture(26)
list = im_num
console.log(list);
```

> i don't know what i'm doing wrong here

```
var yetha = OddNumFinder(collConjecture(26))
console.log(yetha);
```

Comment: `console.log` returns nothing (`undefined`), so the value of `yetha` is `undefined`.

Comment: collConjecture returns nothing. You are passing void to OddNumFinder function.

Comment: Just add what error yor are facing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

```
//Takes a number and checks for odd
function OddNumFinder(x) {
  if (x%2 == 1) {
    console.log(x + ' is a odd number');
    x = x%2
  }
}


function collConjecture(x) {
  im_num = []
  while (x !== 1) {
      if (x%2 == 1) {
          x = (x*3)+1
      } else {
          x = x/2
      }
      im_num.push(x)
  }
  return im_num
}

//call map on each number to check for odd
collConjecture(26).map(item => {
  OddNumFinder(item)
})
```

Output :-

```
13 is a odd number
5 is a odd number
1 is a odd number
```